# format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *'

Tags: c

I get this error: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Werror,-Wformat]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[5] = {0};

    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    }
    printf("%i", arr);
}
```

Comment: `arr` is an array, which decays to a pointer `int*` when passed to a function. It isn't the `int` expected by the format specifier `%i`.

Comment: There's no "print all" format specifier for an array. If you want to print the array, you need to `printf` in a loop.

Comment: you cant print a whole array with one printf if thats what you are trying to do, you have to loop

Comment: Aside: notice that `arr[0]` has not been written to, since the initialisation, unlike all the other array elements.

Comment: You may want to read this: [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471)

Comment: This question lacks a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, whenever you pass an array to a function, only a pointer to the first element of said array is passed into the function (this is called ["array to pointer decay"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471)).
In order to print every element inside an array, you have to access every single one of them and print them individually, using the `[]` operator. Like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    printf("%i", arr[i]);
}
```

Also, remember that arrays are 0 based, meaning `arr[0]` is the first element, but `arr[5]` is not a valid element, as it's out of bounds.